# How do the products in the Elemental Evil line relate to each other?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, princes-of-the-apocalypse

According to this [article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/davidewalt/2015/01/20/dungeons-dragons-returns-to-the-temple-of-elemental-evil/) the new 5th edition campaign ties in with the new board game. I have a few friends who are interested in learning D&D and my current group is almost finished with Rise of Tiamat. So I was thinking of buying the board game depending on how it ties into the campaign book that I already have.

I would like to know how the board game relates to the campaign from someone who has played both, or at least owns both and can look at both.

I am hoping that the board game Temple of Elemental Evil precedes the Chapter "Temple of the Evil Elemental Eye" in the campaign book. That way I can introduce the new players through the board game (something I think may be more accessible to them as gamers) and either dovetail the characters into the campaign, or at least provide insight for them when they play the full campaign.

Comment: This may be informative: https://boardgamegeek.com/blogpost/41192/designer-diary-temple-elemental-evil-or-crafting-s

Answer (score 6):

I own both the board game and the book. They are related only in theme. The locations are the same, but the stories from each are completely different from each other. For example, the "boss" of the board game is a black dragon. This dragon is never mentioned in PotA.

That said, the adventure system games are a great introduction to the basic mechanics of D&D (roll a d20 and add a modifier then compare to a target number) and give you tons of great minis to use in either the board game and the rpg.